# Ubuntu 18.04 Emergency mode on boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, hardware, ram

My Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't boot into the OS, giving this image after Grub. I do not remember making any kernel updates or updating any disk partition recently. [image]

I've tried the following.

1. I have a dual boot, and booting into Windows partition works fine - this rules out RAM issue.
2. Able to boot into a live Ubuntu Disc successfully.
3. Ran a memcheck using the live boot disk, and it says no errors found.
4. System has enough space.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the filesystems was corrupt.

I booted into a live cd, and doing `e2fsck /dev/sdb5` fixed some inodes. rebooting solved the problem after that.